# AT89C5131A-UM Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

Is there any smaller in size version of AT89C5131A-UM microcontroller? Or a small size microcontroller that has the same function as AT89C5131A-UM? I'm finding a mircocontroller that can be placed inside a key fob (Transmitter) .

Comment: Is 7mm by 7mm not small enough?

Answer (score 3):

Without additional detail such as number of GPIOs and ADC pins needed, timers, package constraints (can the project handle wafer-scale ICs or BGAs?), and actual constraints defining "small" (size, pin-count, other?), a specific answer is impractical.

However: Identifying a suitable "small" microcontroller is a much-detested but essential step in many of my designs, so here are some of the typical steps.

1. List out all pin requirements, e.g.

   - How many GPIOs needed
   - How many ADC pins needed
   - How many of the GPIOs need to be directly mapped to timers
   - Hardware serial (UART / USART / I2C / SPI) pins needed - Those generally map to specific pins
   - Pins that require input state-change interrupt support (if the MCU has this at all)
   - Inbuilt comparators needed (if the MCU has this at all)
   - Internal analog reference pins (if the MCU has this at all)
   - Any other specific pinouts needed, e.g. DAC or PWM pins (if the MCU has these at all)
2. List out all peripherals or functionality required within the MCU, e.g.

   - Timers
   - High resolution (16 bit or 32 bit) timers
   - Hardware PWM
   - Hardware UART / USART / SPI / I2C
   - Internal RC oscillator clock source
   - Analog comparator
   - ADC
   - DAC
   - USB PHY
   - Real Time Clock
   - Low power / ultra-low power modes
   - Amount of RAM, FLASH and EEPROM storage
3. List out package constraints, e.g.

   - What formats are acceptable: BGA? Wafer-scale? Chip-on-Glass? VQFN? SOIC? Or only DIP?
   - What is the minimum pin pitch the production process can use? 0.5 mm? 0.25 mm? Or no smaller than 1.27 mm?
   - Must the MCU be available in both DIP (for prototypes) and SMD (for production)?
   - Must the package support the use of a ZIF programming socket before insertion into production boards?
   - Is there a physical board area constraint that might require cutting down desired functionality just to fit in the available space?
4. What are the price constraints?

   - For small volumes on a client-billable product, this may not be a constraint, but for huge volumes, a 1 cent price difference adds up to a fair bit.
   - Also, discount patterns for volume purchases vary widely between parts, even from the same MCU manufacturer
5. What are the end-of-life constraints?

   - For a guaranteed single production run, even an obsolete part may be viable if available in new-old-stock.
   - For a product expected to see production over the next 10 years, a manufacturer's commitment of part availability makes or breaks decisions
6. What are the lead time constraints?

   - Some parts, especially niche products or packages, and some manufacturers have big lead times, so even if a first production run can be met with existing stock, there may be logistical nightmares in the future.
7. Second-source or minimum-rework (code compatible) alternatives

   - The lower end ARM parts sometimes allow switching manufacturers and specific parts with reasonably small effort
   - Some 8051 compatible MCUs are drop in replacements for each other
   - Sometimes code compatibility is good enough to permit entirely changing the product family without massive redevelopment, e.g. if using the Wiring platform (e.g. Arduino, Energia), switching between AVR and Tiva-C may be viable

I am sure some of the stalwarts on this site can add a large number of other parameters, but the above points are a good start.

Once all these parameters are defined, a parametric search on the manufacturer's site is generally the best way to narrow down the choices. Even so, a careful study of the datasheets of shortlisted products is essential. For instance, the Atmel atMEGA168/328 DIP versions have 2 ADC pins less than the SMD versions, while being internally identical.

---

After analyzing all the above parameters, a decision that is not tightly tuned to the defined parameters often still makes sense. For instance:

The Atmel ATmega328 and the Texas Instruments MSP430G2553 are personal favorites because then have both DIP and SMD packages available, boast a good number of GPIOs each, both have decent amounts of memory, and are widely used, hence ensuring extended availability and excellent volume pricing. Thus, there are some designs where a much smaller package or a simpler MCU would amply serve the purpose, but the NRE cost saved by reusing code from earlier projects makes it worthwhile to stick with one or the other of these.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm actually wanting to create a new transmitter (key fob) that can store a set of PRNG's codes. Is there a simple mircocontroller in the market I can use?

Comment: Depending on which microcontrollers you are familiar with, and your power and RF requirements, there would be a range of choices. For ultra low power and the simple functionality you mention, either an Atmel ATTiny45/85 in TSOP-8 or a TI MSP430G2452 in QFN-16 package should work for you. Actually so would many other microcontrollers, so that deserves some research and perhaps a fresh question.